# Как запустить Node.js приложение

Tags: windows, node.js

Как запустить `server.js` с помощью node? `node.exe` находится в `C:\Program Files\nodejs`. А `server.js` находится в `Z:\home\localhost\www\server`

Answer (score 5):

Если вы устанавливали NodeJS с помощью стандартного установщика с официального сайта, то так:

1. Открываем консоль **cmd**
2. Переходим в папку `Z:\home\localhost\www\server` командой `cd Z:\home\localhost\www\server`
3. Запускаем сервер `node server.js`

Comment: Я node.exe кинул прямо в директорию "www\server" и запускаю прямо так: > node js/server.js.

Comment: Выдал ошибку (как обычно):
module.js:340
throw err;
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Windows\system32\server.js'
и т.д...

Comment: Попробуй >node .\server.js

Comment: C:\Windows\system32\server.js как-бы намекает на то, что вы не сделали cd

Comment: Набрав cd "D:\Server\home\localhost\www\server", следующая строчка была: C:\Windows\system32>

Comment: > следующая строчка была: C:\Windows\system32>

что, как-бы, намекает на то, что cd не произошло :)

Comment: `cd` произошло, не произошла смена диска. еще надо `d:` до или после `cd`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Устанавливаете NodeJS
2. Создаете файл mywebserver.js
3. Добавляете в содержание mywebserver.js

   ```
   const http = require('http');
   const hostname = 'localhost';
   const port = 8080;
   http.createServer((req, res) => {
     res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
     res.end('Hello World\n');
   }).listen(port, hostname, () => {
     console.log('Server running at http://${',hostname,'}:${',port,'}/');
   });
   ```
4. Открываете правой кнопкой мыши mywebserver.js c помощью программы Node.js
5. Открываете ссылку в браузере http://localhost:8080/

Answer (score 1):

```
1.Устанавливаем nodeJS
2.запускаем cmd и вводим node --version, там должно вывестись информация о версии нод,если есть значит вы правильно установили нод
3.переходим к директории где лежит ваш скрипт server.js:
 > cd Z:\home\localhost\www\
 > node server.js
```

PS: но все же лучше установить Linux(что я и сделал недавно;)), там более удобно работать с терминалом. можно Linux установить вторым ОС)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй исполняемый файл server.js запустить через контекстное меню. Правая кнопка-->Открыть с помощью-->И выбираеш Node. В командной строке должно появиться Server runnig at http://127.0.0.1:8124/. И дальше вбиваеш этот адрес в браузер.

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью VSCode.

Если скачать NodeJS, то можно будет запустить JS-код в VSCode.

Просто устанавливаем NodeJS, потом заходим в VSCode, и в верхнем меню надо нажать "RUN", потом можно выбрать, с помощью чего мы хотим запустить код, мы вибираем "С помощью NodeJS". Выйдет консоль, и там будет результат.

Answer (score -1):

Прописать переменную PATH, если не прописана, перейти в папку с server.js, а там уже запустить node server.js.

Answer (score -2):

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe Z:\home\localhost\www\server\server.js
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.